# My nodejs install has not the String.localCompare method. Why?

Tags: javascript, node.js, string-comparison

Title is quite clear, but this code example will make it crystal clear :

```
> node
> 'at'.localCompare
undefined
> 'at'.compare
```

As I guess this will be the next question, here are informations on my environment

```
> npm version
{ npm: '5.2.0',
  ares: '1.10.1-DEV',
  cldr: '31.0.1',
  http_parser: '2.7.0',
  icu: '59.1',
  modules: '57',
  node: '8.1.4',
  openssl: '1.0.2l',
  tz: '2017b',
  unicode: '9.0',
  uv: '1.12.0',
  v8: '5.8.283.41',
  zlib: '1.2.11' }
```

Considering that, how to get localCompare back in my environment ?

Comment: Are you sure you didn't misspell it? It's localeCompare. Even browser does not have localCompare

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function `localCompare` do not exist, `localeCompare` does.

[image]